# Couchbase crawls when a node goes down? Shouldn't it fail fast?

Tags: couchbase, nosql

Hello we are testing CB enterpise 2.5 and java client 1.4.3 (newest).

We have a 3 node cluster and it works fantastic when all is up.  When we kill on process (but don't fail over) we notice a huge difference in performance.  It is able to serve the documents on the other two nodes very quickly but the ops plummets because it waits for a timeout every time we try to get a document from the failed node.  The java client is supposed to be robust, and definitely the server.  Both of these things should know the node is down, why is it waiting the full timeout until it fails?  Shouldn't it realize that the node is down and immediately error out or get from replica?

Are we doing something wrong?  We have opTimeout to 2500ms, shouldOptimize = true, and even switched the protocol to binary.  We also tried manually setting the FailureMode to Redistribute.

Are we doing something wrong or is this the spec of couchbase?  Because currently the db get overwhelmed waiting for timeouts  for 2.5 seconds when previously it is doing 5k operations per second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Between a node becoming unavailable and it getting failed over (user-configurable value) any requests to a "dead" node will wait for the timeout period before reporting a timeout to the user.

As such, all requests to that "dead" node *will fail* until a failover occurs - so your op/s will go down by definition as in your case 33% of your data is currently unavailable.

If you are using the synchronous API calls, then you also have the problem that requests to healthy nodes may be backed up behind requests to the "dead" node, and so you have a 2.5s wait in the application before it can continue with other work. This is a good reason why the asynchronous APIs are more performant. In this case, to alleviate the effect on the requests to the other, healthy nodes you can reduce the timeout value to "fail faster"and move onto the next request sooner.

Comment: Well we ended up fixing it a different way.  We still have to test it though.  For java, when doing the CouchbaseConnectionFactory we set the FailureMode to FailureMode.Cancel.  This lets the client cancel any request to a node that is deemed down.

On top of that I think there is a bug on the FailureMode.Redistribute.  In the API pages there are 3 FailureModes.  Retry - which continually retries until timeout is reached, this will get the request if failover is initiated or node comes back up before timeout, Cancel - which immediately cancels reqeuests with a CancelledException.

Comment: (continued) The last mode is 'Redistribute' which queries a node, realizes it is down then goes to the next logical node to get the data (I'm assuming from replica).  But this doesn't work. It acts just like Retry

Comment: @user2615862 I'm sure those failure modes are from the old (pre-Couchbase) spymemcached layer, and so aren't supported for Couchbase buckets. (In memcached-only days where it was a (lossy) cache, redistribute would just use the next node in the list as the cache).

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution, which is available through Couchbase's REST API.
Actually the whole admin console is based on the REST API, so every function there is available from your application.
The lowest value for autofailover is 30 seconds, but you can initiate a failover at any time you want.

[Couchbase REST API failover](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.5/cb-rest-api/#requesting-node-failover)

The failover is nearly instantaneous. Of course after that a rebalance is recommended.

Comment: We are doing testing. We don't want to fail over the node...fail overs are bad.  90% of the time if a node goes down systems will have it up soon.  We are testing how couchbase will act during a failure before failover.